# Android Photo Gallery from Amazon s3

Tags: android

Im aiming to create an Android app that allows me to gather images from my Amazon instance and then scroll horizontally through them like a photo gallery.

Ive currently got an app that scrolls through fragments, but im not sure how to place imageviews inside these fragments

Im relatively new to Android and so was wondering if there are any library's available that help accomplish this task? Or is there a way to download the images from the instance, place them in imageviews and then attach them to the fragments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Download the Amazon AWS SDK [here](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/). Add the aws-android-sdk jar lib file to your project.

2) Go download [this library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io//download_io.cgi). Add it to your project too. IOUtils will help retrieve the byte array easily.

3) Go get your Security Credentials from AWS and put them in your code as constants.

4) Initialize the AmazonS3Client as the SDK examples do:

```
private AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
            new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_KEY,
                    AWS_SECRET));
```

5) Create an AsyncTask subclass to manage the download in a separated thread. [More info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you're not familiar with this class.

In the doInBackground method, if you need to get a list of images to retrieve, you can get a list of files in a bucket, and examine the keys:

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(<your bucket name>));
List<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummaries = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
for (S3ObjectSummary summary : objectSummaries) {
    String key = summary.getKey();
    // do something with the key
}
```

6) Then, add this chunk of code to download the bytes and throw them in a Bitmap object:

```
S3ObjectInputStream content = s3Client.getObject(<your bucket name>, <the key of the targeted file>).getObjectContent();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(content);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

7) Probably in the onPostExecute or something called from that, add the generated Bitmap to your ImageView with imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: nice implementation buddy